# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (anonymous function)

Tags: jquery, xpages

My Xpages is as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<script scr="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script scr="js/pdf.min.js"></script>
<script scr="js/jquery-pdfdoc.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-pdfdoc.css"></link>
<div style="width : 800px height: 600px;">
<div id="mypdfdoc"></div>
    </div>
<xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
        $('document').ready(function(){
        $('#mypdfdoc').PDFDoc( { source : '1.pdf' } );
    });
        ]]></xp:this.value>
</xp:scriptBlock>   
</xp:view>
```

I'm getting the error mentioned above in Google chrome.
What does that mean ? Isn't jquery loaded or does this means something else ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You javascript tags are wrong: It has to be *src* not *scr*:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/pdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-pdfdoc.js"></script>
```

Comment: It seems I was to tired :(

Answer (score 0):

This seems that you are getting some conflict in scripts. try this one and see if helps:

```
var jq = jquery.noConflict(); 
jq('document').ready(function($){
    $('#mypdfdoc').PDFDoc( { source : '1.pdf' } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet (under required #), but [Sven Hasselbach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1254944/sven-hasselbach) is 100% correct. I got one of these yesterday and tracked it down immediately.

It gets thrown when the handle for jQuery (uses $, which also gets used in different syntax for the on-load computation of JavaScript by XPages) can't find what it's looking for, so if the jQuery library can't get a handle on a field (say an EditBox I turned Visibility off on for some cleaner testing), it's going to claim you're talking jive and complain about it. So, since your libraries were defined with "scr=" instead of "src=", jQuery wasn't kicking in for the handled action.

Hope this is a good explanation beyond the immediate solution.